# Specify matrix row error

Tags: python-3.x, input

So I have a matrix like:

```
1 2 3 4
0 3 4 1
7 3 4 5
```

And I want to select a row,then use this row to do stuff on it such as sorting it with some algorithms;I made this so far:

```
def row_management(matrix):

   theline = input('wich line?') #enter row number
   thelist = [matrix[theline]]  #go take the right row of the matrix
   menu_thelist(thelist)  #supossed to use the row and take it to the list management menu
```

However, when I run this, it always return an error "[matrix[theline]] TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" and I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to convert to int

```
theline = int(input('wich line?'))
```

And also

```
thelist = matrix[theline]
```

the have [1,2,3] and not [[1,2,3]](wich cause further problem)

Answer (score 1):

The [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) call returns a `str` type, so it can not be used directly as index to the list in`matrix[theline]`, which is also what the error message says.  Instead do:

```
matrix[int(theline)]
```